# AngularJs to Php

Tags: php, angularjs

How can I get the content of an angular variable to php?

I can use the angular variable in my php code, for example

`print_r({{myVariable}})` would print the content on the page.

But if I try to get the content to a php variable the same way:

```
$myPhpVariable = print_r({{myVariable}})
```

it will just contain the string '{{myVariable}}' and not the content.

This would be because angularjs is client side, but is there a way to solve this?

Comment: why do you need to use angularJS in your PHP. AngularJS is meant to be used as a client of your PHP backend service. If the purpose is to debug the application then you can use `console.log()` in frontend.

Comment: I want to get the tempo for all tracks in my Spotify playlists, so I'm using a demo web app from Spotify built with Angular. There isn't any js wrapper that can get track info from Echonest (that's where I get the BPM) so I'm using a php wrapper for the Echonest Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS runs on the Front end. PHP runs on the back end. You can not pass Javascript variables to PHP in this way, despite the fact that you can pass PHP variables to your Javascript. This is because your files are processed by PHP but your PHP files are not processed by Javascript or, more specifically, AngularJS.

You need to pass it back, via a request. For example, if you've got a php file, `myfile.php`. It might look like this:

```
$variable = $_GET["myVariable"];

// Do something with $variable
```

Then in your Javascript, you can make an AJAX request using the Angular `$http` service.

```
$http.get('myfile.php?myVariable=' + myVariable);
```

This will pass it back to PHP and make it available on the server side, but you can't use the Angular `{{myVariable}}` syntax because PHP doesn't get processed by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

send ajax request in your php file

angular js service

```
$http.post('your php file pat ', {'myVariable':myVariable}).success(function(data){
        callBack(data);
      });
```

and your php file

```
$data =file_get_contents("php://input");
if ($data){
$myPhpVariable = $data->myVariable;

}
```